# How to crawl several pages with the same url using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to get all the reviews of a product from IHerb.com .

https://www.iherb.com/r/California-Gold-Nutrition-Omega-3-Premium-Fish-Oil-100-Fish-Gelatin-Softgels/62118

But the problem is, there are several pages with the same url.

How do I solve this? Here is my code for one page (doesn't really work). Thanks.

[html iHerb.com pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1U78.png)

[html iHerb.com review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF5eH.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.iherb.com/r/California-Gold-Nutrition-Omega-3-Premium-Fish-Oil-100-Fish-Gelatin-Softgels/62118'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "review-test"})

for each in links:
   print(each.text)
```

Comment: Using the network tab of the inspector while clicking on those page buttons, it looks like JavaScript on the page is making network requests for the reviews, which are returned as JSON. Those requests have a `page=` parameter in the URL, so you can probably use those without having to parse HTML. (You should make sure that you're not violating the website's terms of service, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web scraping with Python often requires no more than the use of the Beautiful Soup module to reach the goal. However, [iherb](https://www.iherb.com/r/California-Gold-Nutrition-Omega-3-Premium-Fish-Oil-100-Fish-Gelatin-Softgels/62118) uses JavaScript links.Therefore, your code is not working with only beautiful soups library.
You can use Selenium to automate web browser interaction . With Selenium, programming a Python script to automate a web browser is possible. Afterwards, those pesky JavaScript links are no longer an issue.
Selenium starts a browser session. For Selenium to work, it must access the browser driver. By default, it will look in the same directory as the Python script.The example code below uses Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.iherb.com/r/California-Gold-Nutrition-Omega-3-Premium-Fish-Oil-100-Fish-Gelatin-Softgels/62118")
source_data = browser.page_source
page_soup = soup(source_data, "html.parser")
links=page_soup.findAll('div',{"class":"review-text"})
for each in links:
    print(each.text)
```

Link of selenium is [Selenium packages](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)
I hope that helps :)

**Result**

```
I'm so glad i found this.  Most fish gel are made of gelatin and since i'm looking 
for only halal source, i'm glad i found this brand with an excellent price to match!

We have consumed 3 bottles n i love it.  It makes my breastmilk thicker too.  

Highly recommended!
If only Pharma companies realize that they are missing huge Muslim consumers by using 
Pork geltin. Havent tried it yet, but have mostly everything i was looking for. 
except if it was once a day capsule with added vitamin D3. i have been ordering from 
iHerb for years now from UAE and this has to be one of the best online shopping with 
Fast DHL shipping (Always). I hope they consider stocking more Halal or Kosher 
Gelatin Medicine.  

6th Jan 2016 Update: I started with a 5 Star with above comments, but now after 
consuming for some time i noticed my LDL level have increased. So 2 stars for now.
I've never bought FISH OIL / supplement in capsule/softgel except it is made from 
fish or vege. This is the best Omega 3 in the market. it is good for cardiovascular 
and using selected small fishes like Sardines, Mackerel and Anchovies which are less 
toxin compared to big fishes with high toxin over their longer lives. Furthermore I 
did test this fish oil and it didn't dissolve Styrofoam cup indicating there is no 
ethanol used in the process of getting oil as we know that ethanol is not good for 
our organs in long term (search "ethanol fish oil" in Youtube)... Click on my name 
HAFIZ (the above green text) to get more info.
I love this omega 3 fish oil very much because it's very cheap yet effective and 
doesn't contain any harmful chemicals. I've already tried a lot of brands of omega 3 
and this one is one of the best and effective. Also, when using this I noticed that 
I'm more energized and my body is stronger and healthier. >>Press "click meeee"button 
to view and use my code for Discount at Checkout
Best with great price
So good

good product like website say 
very good product. 
I bought the product two months ago, and still didn't get it. what is the 
problem? 
Could you please check it?
good!
Exelent product 
Love it use it more than 4 months
```